# I knew in and == has same precedence in python. but strange result happens

Tags: python

```py
number = 3
numbers = []
if number in numbers == False:
    numbers.append(number)

print(numbers)
```

I guess numbers has 3. but it has nothing.

why is this??

Comment: _Comparison chaining_ makes that `number in numbers and numbers == False`.

Comment: comparison chaining https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Answer (score 4):

```
number in numbers == False
```

is [comparison operator chaining](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/#:%7E:text=The%20chaining%20of%20operators%20can,arithmetic%2C%20shifting%20or%20bitwise%20operation.) and equivalent to:

```
number in numbers and numbers == False
```

This is similar to the more immediately obvious examples:

```
1 < a < 5
x == y == z
```

In order to make your test work as you expect, you would have to mark precedence by parentheses:

```
(number in numbers) == False
```

or simply use the recommended:

```
number not in numbers
```